# Mobile version of of Template C in PayPal Hosted Checkout

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I am using PayFlow Pro hosted checkout Template C.  I cannot get a mobile version of the template.  I have tried putting the template, mobile in the key / values pairs on the initial request for the token and also putting the template='mobile' in the iframe request.

Neither seems to work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Layout C, PayPal does not automatically redirect mobile users to a mobile-optimized flow. The reason is that if PayPal automatically showed a mobile optimized embedded template, within a merchant web page that may not be mobile optimized, this can create unexpected and undesirable results. To display the mobile checkout pages for Layout C, the Partner or Merchant must detect the supported mobile browser and then explicitly pass the form post parameter: template=mobile...however...I was just informed that there may be an issue with this feature on our end. I'll update this answer via comment shortly.

Comment: @rkfdsam the consensus here is that for mobile it is better to use layout A or B. because they are optimized for mobile...because the hosted page takes up the entire screen of the device, the embedded page wont work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Point of clarification.  Is there an issue with Template=mobile on Template C? Will it be resolved? I would prefer to keep the user within our site and open another page or tab during the checkout.

Comment: I think it is less an issue with passing the parameter than with the physical size of layout C...there would not be enough room on the mobile device screen to display a page with layout C embedded. Based on my research and the answers I received I dont believe they are going to make any changes to Layout C.